# Conditional probability of coin tosses

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have the following events:

- X = "Number of heads in the first two tosses"
- Z = "Number of tosses before first head".

I have to compute $P(Z=1 | X=1)$. I can proceed as follows:
$$ P(Z=1 | X=1) = \frac{P(Z=1 , X=1)}{P(X=1)}.$$

I can compute easily with the Binomial the denominator but I have no idea about the numerator. I know that the result should be $pq$ if the probability of getting head is $p$. Is there a way to *visualize* this probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of tosses before the first head is $1$, then in the first two tosses you have necessarily gotten exactly a single head, which means that
$$
(Z = 1)\subseteq (X = 1)
$$
as events. Consequently
$$
P(Z = 1, X = 1) = P(Z = 1)
$$

Comment: I can't really understand why in the first two tosses I have a single head.

Comment: Because that's what $Z = 1$ implies: that the first toss is a tails, and the second toss is a heads. As we see, this means that among the first two tosses, there is exactly one heads.